# Get strings from a list in a dataframe into a single list

Tags: python, string, dataframe, list

I feel this must be pretty straighforward but for some reason the fact that the string is within a list in a cell it's throwing me a lot of errors or a weird output.

My dataframe column df["splitted"] is like this:

```
0                                                       []
1        ['yolanda', 'contento', 'profesor', 'companeri...
2        ['solicitar', 'cambio', 'salon', 'hija', 'ser'...
```

What I want to get it's a single list with all the strings:

```
['yolanda', 'contento', 'profesor','companerito','solicitar', 'cambio', 'salon', 'hija', 'ser'...]
```

But I either get something like:

```
['[]',
 "['yolanda', 'contento', 'profesor', 'companerito']",
```

```
0                                                      [,]
1        [,',y,o,l,a,n,d,a,',,, ,',c,o,n,t,e,n,t,o,',,,...
2        [,',s,o,l,i,c,i,t,a,r,',,,
```

```
["['[]'",
 ',',
 '"[\'yolanda\'',
 ',',
 "'contento'",
```

I have tried

```
words = df["splitted"].str.join(',')
words = df["splitted"].tolist()
words = [s.strip() for s in word
```

but I cannot seem to be able to access each string of the list and I'm sure there must a be more direct method to access the elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the full examples of how you "tried" these things.

Comment: Are you sure `df['splitted']` is a list, not a string that looks like a list?

Comment: What does `type(df.loc[0]['splitted'])` say?

Comment: @Barmar no it's not a list but the content of it, type(df.loc[0]['splitted']) it's a string

Comment: then you should convert it to a list and process that. Use `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: @ScottHunter I just did which show what I wrote in the output

Comment: How are you creating the df? Can you fix it so the elements are lists rather than strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse the string representation of a list to an actual list. Then you can concatenate all the lists with `sum()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"splitted": ["[]", "['yolanda', 'contento', 'profesor', 'companeri']", "['solicitar', 'cambio', 'salon', 'hija', 'ser']"]})
result = df['splitted'].apply(ast.literal_eval).sum()
print(result) 
# Output: ['yolanda', 'contento', 'profesor', 'companeri', 'solicitar', 'cambio', 'salon', 'hija', 'ser']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print([b for a in df["splitted"].values for b in a]
```

Alternatively:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.chain(*df["splitted"].values)))
```

The latter may be faster but use more temporary memory. I haven't measured.

If the data is stored as repr strings:

```
import ast

print([b for a in df["splitted"].values for b in ast.literal_eval(a)]
```

Comment: According to a comment, the value is a string, not a list, so this won't work.

Comment: I've extended my answer accordingly. I think your answer is faster.